# Tax subtotal excluding from sale price although settings are not

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, taxes

I have running Magento 1.9.3.7 on PHP5

for some weird reason, tax is acting weird on checkout and cart, first prices are displaying as normal, then on the subtotal, tax is deducted from selling price, and then it adds taxes again, so the total amount is finally the original selling price, instead of price + tax.
[image]
Settings seems to be right, prices are supposed to be excluding taxes, i attached screens of both, checkout and settings, i've read somewhere that there is a bug, but with PHP7, and i have 5.5

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using a third party tax handler? I had a lot of tax issues and ended up getting taxjar :(

Comment: i guess if i cant find a solution to this, im gonna need an extension, but this is so basic stuff, it should work by default as it should on such a big platform as magento...

Comment: i thought the same thing. I just wanted to have my shipping charged differently.

Comment: i just checked taxjar, and it requires a subscription, so no chance, if i cant solve it myself, i will hire a developer in freelancer to fix this crap

Comment: hmm that's an option too, cause all of your settings look right.

Comment: I've read about rounding issues with using the tax calculation based on unit price like this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/164184/70343 but you've got an entirely different scenario.  Do you have any custom discount or surcharge extensions installed?

Comment: No, i dont, i finally pay $50 to a dev to solve it and its now fixed, from what he told me the calculation was off

Comment: you have to create test order and see difference in cart prices and invoice :)

Comment: In fact, paypal was rejecting the charge because the invoice didn’t match the amount reflected, so it could be something related to the theme